# ipv6 transparent proxy usage using apache benchmark(ab) apache2-utils-2.2.22

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, ipv6, web, ab

Would anybody please provide any hints on why the ab is failing work on ipv6 client/server configuration, while ipv4 is working good ?

Thanks in advance

==

Client configuration:

Apache benchmark details:

```
root@VM8-4:~# dpkg -l | egrep apache
ii  apache2-utils                    2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3                   utility programs for webservers



root@VM8-4:~# ab -n 1 -c 1 http://[2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c0d:e0f:1011:1213]/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c0d:e0f:1011:1213 (be patient)...
Test aborted after 10 failures

apr_socket_connect(): Network is unreachable (101)
```

---

```
root@VM8-4:~# ip -6 a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c0d:e0f:1011:1210/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe50:113f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

```
root@VM8-4:~# ip -6 r s
2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c0d:e0f:1011:1210 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 


root@VM8-4:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-29-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012
root@VM8-4:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.0.84
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.0.0
    broadcast 10.10.0.255
    gateway 10.10.0.100
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 10.10.0.100

### Start IPV6 static configuration
iface eth0 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address 2607:f0d0:2001:0a0b:0c0d:0e0f:1011:1210
netmask 128
gateway 2607:f0d0:2001:0a0b:0000:0000:0000:0001
### END IPV6 configuration
root@VM8-4:~# 


root@VM8-4:~# netstat -punta | egrep -nir 'tcp6|80'
10:tcp6       0      0 :::2022                 :::*                    LISTEN      8122/sshd       
root@VM8-4:~#
```

---

Server configuration:

```
root@VM8-6:/opt# netstat -punta | egrep -nir 'tcp6|80'
3:tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30343/apache2   
9:tcp6       0      0 2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c:80 :::*                    LISTEN      30343/apache2   
10:tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1705/sshd       


root@VM8-6:/opt# ip -6 a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c0d:e0f:1011:1213/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:d676/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@VM8-6:/opt# ip -6 r s
2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c0d:e0f:1011:1213 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
root@VM8-6:/opt# netstat -punta | egrep -nir 'tcp6'
9:tcp6       0      0 2607:f0d0:2001:a0b:c:80 :::*                    LISTEN      29557/apache2   
10:tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1705/sshd       
root@VM8-6:/opt# 


root@VM8-6:/opt# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.0.86
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.0.0
    broadcast 10.10.0.255
    gateway 10.10.0.100
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 10.10.0.100

### Start IPV6 static configuration
iface eth0 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address 2607:f0d0:2001:0a0b:0c0d:0e0f:1011:1213
netmask 128
gateway 2607:f0d0:2001:0a0b:0000:0000:0000:0001
### END IPV6 configuration
root@VM8-6:/opt# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-29-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012
```

---

gateway:

```
root@Slot1:~# ip -6 a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2607:f0d0:2001:a0b::1/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a61f:72ff:fec6:8201/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
60: wlan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::861b:5eff:fe9d:983c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@Slot1:~# ip -6 r s
2607:f0d0:2001:a0b::1 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev wlan1  proto kernel  metric 256 
root@Slot1:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your systems have a `/128` mask, while they *should* have a `/64` mask. Only use `/128` for localhost.

In the Debian config, you should change:

```
        netmask 128
```

to

```
        netmask 64
```